# C# CefSharp in new process

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

How can I run my method (LoadUrl) in a new process.
The issue is that CefSharp (https://cefsharp.github.io) is initialized only once, and I can`t reinitialize ex. "User-Agent" on the following request.

I tried start this in new Thread, but it crashes when I try `Cef.Initialize()` after `Cef.ShutDown()`.

Is there any way to start CefSharp each time with new command-line?

My code:

```cs
public void LoadUrl()
{
    Cef.Initialize(InitializeCef());
    CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new CefSharp.OffScreen.ChromiumWebBrowser("", BrowserSettings());
    string URL = "http://localhost:3180/";

    browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
    browser.LoadError += (BrowserLoadError);
    browser.JsDialogHandler = new JsDialogHandler();
    browser.FrameLoadEnd += new EventHandler<FrameLoadEndEventArgs>(browser_FrameLoadEnd);
    while (!browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initializing browser...");
    }
    browser.Load(URL);

    browser.Dispose();
    Cef.Shutdown();
}
private BrowserSettings UniBrowserSettings()
{
    BrowserSettings settings = new BrowserSettings();
    settings.DefaultEncoding = "UTF-8";
    settings.JavascriptAccessClipboard = CefState.Disabled;
    settings.JavascriptOpenWindows = CefState.Disabled;
    settings.JavascriptCloseWindows = CefState.Disabled;
    settings.JavascriptDomPaste = CefState.Disabled;
    settings.OffScreenTransparentBackground = true;

    return settings;
}


private static CefSettings InitializeCef()
{
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.UserAgent = DateTime.Now + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  myBrowser  " + Cef.CefSharpVersion; 
    return settings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CefSharp is designed to be initialized once and as far as I know you cannot re-initialize it after shutting down. I'm not sure why the user agent cannot be set because it looks like UserAgent is a property stored in [CefSettings.h](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/bae3c28e9231febcb620701bfbacae43299c4f5e/CefSharp.Core/CefSettings.h) and Chrome can switch user agents while running.

What you can do instead is create another project within yours that takes a user agent as a command line argument. That process would then create your browser, do the work and exit. Something like this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length > 0 && !String.isNullOrEmpty(args[0]);
               Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings() { UserAgent = args[0] });
        }
    }
```

You would also probably pass the url as a parameter, which you could validate using `Uri.TryCreate` and you should be able to work with that.

Comment: It's a `Chromium` limitation, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/421#comment-16410312

Comment: @amaitland I figured as much for the actual initialization of CefSharp but why wouldn't it be possible to alter the UserAgent once Cef has been initialized? It seems as though there is a getter and setter available for the property right? **edit** I realize what I wrote in the post, editing that now but still curious about the UserAgent

Comment: But I want is not only send but also receive data. Such as - Connection error ... etc.

Comment: @LessNoviceProgrammer `CefSettings` just wraps a `struct`, changing it's values after `Cef.Initialize` is called does nothing.

Comment: @Tommi if you have follow up questions, first start by googling, searching the examples in the project it's self. You can change the `UserAgent` sent in the request headers for every request, you should be able to search and find examples for that also.

Comment: @amaitland  I know about this method (header). But this method is not suitable. A Javascript then you can learn the real meaning of User-Agent. And do not send me to Google. I'm without you know how to use it!

Comment: @Tommi Do you expect people are going to help you with that sort of attitude? Good luck....

Comment: @amaitland What kind of my attitude?

Comment: @Tommi your comment is outside the scope of the original question. If you want to send and receive requests you don't need a browser, use the [HTTPClient Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) to do that. Additionally, Google is your friend you'd be a fool to not use it.

Comment: @amaitland I'm sorry that it happened. I'm sorry that I replied in the same spirit. I then had a very bad day. Sorry.